# Database design: Foreign keys dilemma

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a web based application for a big company and i have a question about the database part. Lets first introduce you to the situation:

There are 4 very tables that are connected with foreign keys:

**Table 1: roadlists**

```
roadlist (roadListNumber, vehicleId, driverId, date, start, end, fuel,...)
```

- roadListNumber - primaryKey
- vehicleId - foreignKey
- driverId - foreignKey

**Table 2: drivers**

```
drivers(driverId, firstName, middleName, lastName, and so on...)
```

- driverId - primaryKey

**Table 3: vehicles**

```
vehicles(vehicleId, group, type, model, gpsDevice, and so on...)
```

- vehicleId - primaryKey

**Table 4: cargo_zones**

```
cargo_zones(zoneId, name, permiter, area, latitures, longtitudes, and so on...)
```

- zoneId - primaryKey

**Table 5: roadLists_cargoZones_mapping**

```
roadLists_cargoZones_mapping(roadListNumber, zoneId, spentFuel, tkm, mcm,...)
```

- roadListNumber - foreignKey

So here is the problem:

If i delete a driver from drivers table the value in the roadlists table will be set to NULL or the whole row will be deleted based on the constraints. In the first case if it is set to NULL if somebody lists all the reports for some date he will not be able to see the driver's name who was on duty because its id does not link to any row in the drivers table. In the seconds case if the whole row is removed from the roadlists table the system loses important data.

So how do i deal with this kind of situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way (but not the only way):

Mark a driver as deleted (have a boolean deleted column, or call it `IsActive`), without actually deleting the driver or related information.

This way you can still historically report. One way to approach this is create views over the table; one view for AllDrivers and one for ActiveDrivers and join to these rather than the table directly, or just add the `IsActive` predicate to your query `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

The way you deal with this situation is DON'T DELETE the row from the Driver table.

This is information you want to keep. So, don't remove it.

What you might need is a way to mark the Driver row as inactive, archived, unavailable, or whatever. You've got a status change, NOT a delete.

Any queries where you need that driver EXCLUDED, you can add a predicate (a condition in the WHERE clause) to exclude those rows.